# GridViewRowPresenter using Datagrid's columns

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, datagrid

Is there any way of feeding the columns of a `Datagrid` to a `GridViewRowPresenter` ?

It cannot be done directly, as one uses `DataGridColumn` and the other `GridViewColumn` so this doesn't work:

```
<GridViewRowPresenter Columns="{Binding ElementName=myDataGrid, Path=Columns, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this, but something like this should work:

```
public class MyGridViewRowPresenter : GridViewRowPresenter
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty NumberOfColumnsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("NumberOfColumns", typeof(int), typeof(MyGridViewRowPresenter), new PropertyMetadata(0));

    public int NumberOfColumns
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(NumberOfColumnsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(NumberOfColumnsProperty, value); }
    }

    public override void EndInit()
    {
        base.EndInit();
        for (var i = 0; i < NumberOfColumns; i++)
        {
            Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn());
        }
    }
}
```

usage

```
 <local:MyGridViewRowPresenter NumberOfColumns="{Binding ElementName=myDataGrid, Path=Columns.Count, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

I did something similar to a standard grid, so instead of doing row or column definitions and then add column and rows, i would just say columns=somenumber and that would do it.

Comment: I guess MyColumns (xaml) is in fact NumberOfColumns? While this could work, its far from what i want. If i resize one column in the datagrid i need the column in the GridViewRowPresenter to resize simultaneously. You get the idea.

Comment: Yeah I corrected it. I would not know how to do it, I have something in my mind but it would be ugly :).